# Efficient way to do one-hot encoding in R on large data

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a one-hot representation of my data. This is my approach:

```
data(iris)
iris = as.data.frame(apply(iris, 2, function(x) as.factor(x)))
head(iris)

iris_ohe <- data.frame(model.matrix(~.-1, iris))
head(iris_ohe)
dim(iris_ohe)
```

The thing is, the data I'm working on has over 1 million rows, and doing the encoding, I get a matrix with over 100 columns. This is too much for `R` and I run out of memory:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10204.5 Gb
```

Is there a better approach I could try?

Comment: This means that you have to many factors to encode. Are you sure this is really what you want to do?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparse.model.matrix.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `mltools::one_hot`

```
require(mltools)
require(data.table)

n <- 1e6

df1 <- data.table( ID= seq(1:n), replicate(99, sample(0:1,n,TRUE)))

one_hot(df1)
```

No memory issues for me and it runs almost instantly

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. `data.table` may do some initial memory serialization/compression, but once it has to one hot encode, memory does expand dramatically. For example, I've a 1GB file with a column of factors, about 830, and once one hot encoding begins, this quickly expands to 120+ GB in memory. A real solution would be to run this process as a stream using something like Python or even awk.

Comment: It works fine for data on OP's scale... If you need a solution that scales more effectively, you might ask a new question.

Comment: I was well able to write up a solution for the data of my size using the logic I mentioned in my comment above

Answer (score 4):

`sparse.model.matrix` from the `Matrix` package is a sparse equivalent for `model.matrix` and avoids the *cannot allocate vector* problem.

Comment: As a quick note: `sparse.model.matrix()` and `model.matrix()` don't do one-hot encoding but create dummy variables. The difference being that OHE creates one variable for each observed value, whereas dummy variables drop the first group to avoid the dummy variable trap.